# Html Model Box not work loop in laravel view

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, laravel-5

I want to show texts in web-page using loop with html Modal Box.texts saved in database.I am using laravel framework.only show modal box for first item, maybe it can be JavaScript not loading problem.
I used https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modals.asp Modal box tutorials.used that css and javascript code.

just used w3schools code.

```
<div class="row">
    @foreach($dw as $ad)
        <!-- single product -->
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">
            <div class="single-product">
                <!--{{$ad->image}}-->
                <div>
                    <img class="img-fluid" src="{{ asset('img/' . $ad->image) }}" alt="">
                </div>

                <div class="product-details">
                    <h3 col-xl-5>{{$ad->jobtype}}</h3>
                    <div class="price col-xl-11">
                        <h6 col-xl-12>{{$ad->jobC}}</h6>
                        <div>
                            <button id="myBtn">Details</button>

                            <!-- The Modal -->
                            <div id="myModal" class="modal">

                                <!-- Modal content -->
                                <div class="modal-content">
                                    <span class="close">&times;</span>
                                    <p>{{$ad->details}}</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="prd-bottom"><a href="{{url('/submitcv')}}">Send Your CV</a></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    @endforeach
```

no errors showing but not working modal box for all sets, only showing first item in loop

Comment: In your HTML, you've hard coded the `id="myBtn"` in your loop. However, id's _must_ be unique within a document. You're also seem to be missing `class=""` on your `h3` and `h6`. You should also add your JS, since that's the code that actually should show your modals.

Comment: can you upload somewhere and I see your result, please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set Id for each modal and open them using the button on click

```
<div class="row">
            @foreach($dw as $ad)
                <!-- single product -->
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6" {{ $makeId = 1 }}>
                    <div class="single-product">

                    <!--{{$ad->image}}-->
                    <div>
                    <img class="img-fluid" src="{{ asset('img/' . $ad->image) }}" alt="">
                    </div>
                        <div class="product-details">
                            <h3 col-xl-5>{{$ad->jobtype}}</h3>
                            <div class="price col-xl-11">
                                <h6 col-xl-12>{{$ad->jobC}}</h6>
                                <div>
                                <button class="myBtn" modal-id="modal-{{ $ad->id }}">Details</button>

                                <!-- The Modal -->
                                <div class="modal" id="modal-{{ $ad->id }}">

                                <!-- Modal content -->
                                <div class="modal-content">
                                    <span class="close">&times;</span>
                                    <p>{{$ad->details}}</p>
                                 </div>

                                </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="prd-bottom"><a href="{{url('/submitcv')}}">Send Your CV</a></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>@endforeach

                <script>
                    $('.myBtn').click(function(){
                        var GetModalId = $(this).attr('modal-id');
                        $("#"+GetModalId).css('display', 'block');
                    });

                    $('.close').click(function(){
                        $('.modal').css('display', 'none');
                    });
                </script>
```

Remember you need to attach jquery to your page to this codes work

you can use this code to attach jquery:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```